# Angular Unit testing : Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/advisor'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine

Am working on unit testing under my angular 4.0.0 app , some method in my  real  component is calling manual routing via :

```
method(){
....
    this.navigateTo('/home/advisor');
....
}
```

with **navigateTo** is a custom routing method calling this :

```
  public navigateTo(url: string) {
    this.oldUrl = this.router.url;
    this.router.navigate([url], { skipLocationChange: true });
  }
```

i have this routing file :

```
import ...     // Components and dependencies

const homeRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'registration',
        component: RegistrationComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'synthese',
            component: SyntheseComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'queue',
            component: QueueComponent,
            children: [
              {
                path: 'queue-modal',
                component: QueueModalComponent
              },
              {
                path: 'confirm',
                component: ConfirmComponent
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'toolbox',
        component: ToolboxComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'appointment',
        component: AppointmentRegistrationComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'appointment-validation',
        component: AppointmentValidationComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'datepicker',
        component: DatePickerComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'validation/:defaultNumber',
        component: ValidationComponent,
        children: [
                   {
                     path: 'synthese',
                     component: SyntheseComponent
                   }
                   ]
      },
      {
        path: 'modalField',
        component: ModalFieldComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'search',
        component: SearchComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'advanced-search',
        component: AdvancedSearchComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'tools',
        component: ToolsComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'advisor',
        component: AdvisorComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'pilote',
        component: PilotComponent
      },
      {
          path: 'blank',
          component: BlankComponent
        },
      {
        path: 'view-360/:id',
        component: View360Component,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'client',
            component: ClientComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'tools',
            component: ToolsAdvisorComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'valid-close',
            component: ValidCloseComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'application',
            component: ApplicationView360Component
          }
        ],
        canActivate: [AuthGuardAdviser]
      },
      {
        path: 'view-360',
        component: View360Component,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'client',
            component: ClientComponent
          }
        ],
        canActivate: [AuthGuardAdviser]
      },
      {
        path: 'contract',
        component: ContractComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'queue-again',
        component: QueueAgainComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'stock',
        component: StockComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'mobile',
            component: MobileComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'stock-level',
            component: StockLevelComponent
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'usefull-number',
        component: UsefullNumberComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'admin',
        loadChildren: 'app/home/admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
        //           component: AdminComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardAdmin]
      },
      {
        path: 'rb',
        loadChildren: 'app/home/rb/rb.module#RbModule',
        //        component: RbComponent
        //        canActivate: [AuthGuardAdmin]
      },
      {
        path: 'tools-advisor',
        component: ToolsAdvisorComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'catalog/:haveClient',
        component: CatalogComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'application',
        component: ApplicationComponent
      },
    ]
  },

   ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(homeRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

Strangely , even my application goes fonctionnally well ,but the test throws this error :

> Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL
>   Segment: 'home/advisor' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'home/advisor'

it seems like i have some missing configuration .

**Any ideas ??**

Comment: Have you properly imported the module where you provided your app routes ?

Comment: yes , functionally , that works well , i haven t noticed any issue , only the unit test is failing due to that @ Ante Jablan Adamović

Comment: You need to import the module inside your `TestBed`, try logging your `router` or add a breakpoint in debug mode and check if there're any registered routes.

Comment: Ante Jablan Adamović im importing the RouterTestingModule like u see

Comment: In your test, did you mock the router module ? If so, how ?

Comment: @trichetriche how to do it ? (i posted my my real routing file , not such a mocked one)

Comment: @firasKoubaa You never  showed us `RouterTestingModule` .... or where you imported your module in `TestBed` configuration.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Following my comment :

When you want to unit test your router, you have to use the testing module, not the actual one.

Start with

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
```

Then, in your Testbed

```
imports: [RouterTestingModule]
```

Now you should be able to unit test your component

**EDIT**

To make a spy on your routing, what you have to do is

```
spyOn(component.router, 'navigate').and.returnValue(true);
```

And you expect will look like

```
expect(component.router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/home/advisor');
```

Comment: @trichetriche   i ve already imported the RouterTestingModule   , i thought that there is some specific manner to do it :RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(appRoutes)  for example , but the problem persist , even after adding that fasmou RouterTestingModule (am understanding ;)  )

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović : not working even with RouterTestingModule

Comment: Well if you imported it, now you have to spy on your method call ! you should not let the component go to another by a route, you're supposed to test the component, not another ! Do you know how to make a spy for the routing ?

Comment: @trichetriche : almost no , if there is an example of doing it , that would be usefull

Comment: I run into the following typescript error when doing the spy as suggested: `Argument of type 'true' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<boolean>'`. However when I change the spy to simply `spyOn(component.router, 'navigate');` it works.

Comment: It supposes that the router is in public visibility, so it does not work with `constructor(private readonly router:Router)` . A better way of access the router is to ask the TestBed for: `const router = TestBed.inject(Router)`

Comment: For Angular 12.2.9 I have done it that way: after describe 
`let router: Router;` then in beforeEach
`router = TestBed.inject(Router);` 
and then in test:
`spyOn(router, 'navigate').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));`
`expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['home', 'advisor']);`

Answer (score 74):

You need `RouterTestingModule.withRoutes` like so:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(
        [{path: 'yourpath', component: BlankComponent}]
      )
    ],
    declarations: [
      BlankComponent,
      YourComponentBeingTested
    ]
  })
  .compileComponents()
}))
```

Comment: @dandy74 Is there a simple way to avoid creation of `BlankComponent`? It would be useful most of the time.

Comment: Supposed your unittest only concerns the current component and this would be a last step in the test scenario, then you can simply use itself without any harm or use redirectTo instead of component: `[{path: 'yourpath', redirectTo: ''}]`.

Comment: [{path: 'yourpath', redirectTo: ''}]. worked for me thanks @Berci

Comment: Just for more clarity for the people, the `BlankComponent` represents the component you are expecting the route `yourpath` to take you to.

Answer (score 2):

I run into same issue. The solution of accepted answer doesn't work for me, because I accidentally added the HttpClientModule instead of HttpClientTestingModule to my Spec files. To avoid the "Can not match any routes" issue be sure you add RouterTestingModule and HttpClientTestingModule everywhere it is needed.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            RouterTestingModule,
            HttpClientTestingModule,
        ],
        declarations: [
            AppComponent
        ],
    }).compileComponents();
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

In my console, I am getting this error while running my unit test case because of **SubRoute**. I am able to fix this issue by implementing the following way in my unit test case.

```
class RouterStub {
        url = '';
        navigate(commands: any[], extras?: any) { }
      }

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                    providers:[{ provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub }]
}).compileComponents();
}));
```